# Managing/storing sessions in database for multiple servers (services) under php

Tags: php, database, zend-framework, session

I am working on a project under ZendFramework 1.11.
For a moment, it's used native php sessions mechanism (Zend_Auth_Storage_Session).

But i have several problems, and decided that storing sessions in databases is best choise. These problems:

- Several services (placed on different servers), that needs to identify user by one cookie. E.g. main website, photos service (that provides api for javascript to work with photos, etc)
- Ability to see all sessions (with info about geolocation and about OS/Browser/last access date) for each account
- Ability to close specified sessions
- Ability to rename session cookie name

I found that we can use custom MySexy_Auth_Storage_Db class, but this way i need to generate session ids by myself, to setup cookies and to do many thigs (that could be unsecure in my implementation)

Maybe you could advise some ready-to-use solutions? Thank you!

P.S. I saw setSaveHandler solution, but it doesn't allow to have custom column in `session` table in database with account_id, for example, to easily manage all user's sessions

Comment: If all servers sit on subdomains under the same domain, you can set the cookie domain to ".example.com" and you will be able to read the session ID from all subdomains. If all servers then access the same session storage (database) with this same session ID, then you have a solution?

Comment: Perhaps this whitepaper could give you some insight into the topic of session clustering as it did to me: http://static.zend.com/topics/Session-Clustering-ZSCM-WP-0610-EN-A4.pdf